# MSAL authentication token issue in angular

Tags: javascript, active-directory, azure-ad-msal

can someone guide me on how to resolve the issue screenshot attach below?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDd4T.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and familiarize yourself with [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this when you are sending the request to the server because you are not sending the header with the request. You can change the origin header.
This solution works most of the time.

> Origin: http://localhost

You can also go to the AAD App registration and make sure that you add the redirect url Over the Single page application. Follow the steps [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2482).